# How to setup nginx to allow access with /suburi on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ubuntu, nginx

We are setting up a nginx web server to allow /suburi access in our rails 3.1 app (such as access URL: http://www.railapp.com/subdomain). The subrui name here is byop. Our rails document root subdir is at /var/www/. The suburi byop is at /var/www/byop. Here is what we did after successful rails deployment:

1. Setup the nginx.conf:

   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name 154.248.209.181;
      root /var/www/;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env production;
      passenger_base_uri /byop;
   }
2. Create symbolic link under /var/www as following:

   ln -s /var/www/byop/current/public /var/www/byop

nginx was stop and restarted. However 403 Forbidden page shows up for http://154.248.209.181/byop

We checked the symbolic link under /var/www and there is no link listed (only the byop subdir). Here is the output of ls -li:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-152-95-60:/var/www$ ls -li
total 4
9296 drwxrwsr-x 4 ubuntu www-data 4096 May  6 03:12 byop
```

What's wrong with our setup above? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem we found is with the step 2 to create the symlink. The name of the subdir and the name of symbolic link are the same. After using different symlink name, the problem solved. Here is the working copy:

```
1. Setup the nginx.conf:

server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name 154.248.209.181; 
    root /var/www/; 
    passenger_enabled on; 
    rails_env production; 
    passenger_base_uri /by; 
 }

2. Create symlink under /var/www as following:

ln -s /var/www/byop/current/public /var/www/by
```

Then http://154.248.209.181/by brings up the page.