# Deploying a Rails app to a sub-URI with Passenger and Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, sinatra, passenger

I am already deployed my Rails app with Passenger and Nginx and it's working fine.
Below is my servier configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/demo/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }
```

Now I want to deploy a second app to a sub URI. Here the [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) is a little unclear.

Could anyone please suggest me what will be the next configuration?

Below is the configuration I am using for my second (Sinatra) application:

```
location /log {
        root   /var/www/logger/public;
        passenger_base_uri /log;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I am getting "404 Not Found". Please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467895/how-to-setup-nginx-to-allow-access-with-suburi-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it's working!

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  location / {
    root   /var/www/demo/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
  }

  location /test {
    root   /var/www/demo;
    passenger_base_uri /test;
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
```

Then:

```
ln -s /var/www/logger/public /var/www/demo/test
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `^~` before the sub-directory:

```
location /log
```

To:

```
location ^~ /log
```